# wanna cry ransomware on LInux ?

Tags: linux, malware

Do Linux users bother about wanna cry ransomware. I am not talking about using windows emulation  like WINE.

All my servers and office desktops are on linux, I am assuming I am safe against at least this ransomware. But I just want to make sure

Comment: You're "safe" if you are on a fully patched windows system. This ransomware targeted the smb protocol and a specific windows vulnerability

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "wannacrypt" (wcrypt) spread via Linux server serving over SMB?](https://serverfault.com/questions/849872/can-wannacrypt-wcrypt-spread-via-linux-server-serving-over-smb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this specific piece of malware only affects Windows  and if you don't run this, you should not be affected at the moment.